# How to set the default gcc version for only one user

Tags: versions, gcc

The question [Choose gcc and g++ version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version) answers how to do it, but I could not figure out, if it only affects me or also all the other users of the system as I have to use `sudo`. I share a server (11.04) with other people and I am the only one who has to use gcc 4-4.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22263/how-to-set-the-default-gcc-version-for-only-one-user

Comment: I've already notified the mods. So I am waiting for them to delete this post.

Comment: I'm not so sure this should be deleted. It has an answer that should work out-of-the-box on Ubuntu systems and *some* other Unix-like systems, but by no means all. Each user's `.profile` file in Ubuntu (and some other OSes, but not all and not, I don't think, even most) contain code to check for the existence of a user's private `bin` directory and add it to the path, on login. So the answer here doesn't go into detail about how to add that directory, whereas the answers at the original question do go into much greater detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up personal links:

```
cd ~
mkdir bin
cd bin
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.4 g++
```

Then, run this whenever you start a new shell, or add it to your .bash_profile, or whatever:

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

And you're done! :)