# How to install a specific version of g++?

Tags: installation, g++

In my Ubuntu there is `g++ --version` -

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I want to have same `g++ --version` on another Linux machine which has -

```
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I alter my **g++** version to be the same as the above?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install g++-4.4`

Comment: @green7 it will overwrite the last version ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the g++-4.1 version from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/g++-4.1). g++-4.1 is not available in the recent Ubuntu repositories. So you need to download the package from the link provided.

Install/compile the download package alongside with the current version of g++.

Then use `update-alternatives` to switch version

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.3 10
```

Change the default version by choosing the appropriate version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Comment: Other versions could be available via apt-get, like `sudo apt-get install g++-6`. Then a `whereis g++-6` could be used to find its location and change update-alternatives appropriately.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @stiv Do you really need g++ 4.1? Well since Lucid Lynk reached EOL in 2013/2015 and once a release reached EOL, the package information is removed from ubuntu packages.

Comment: More details [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-and-setup-gcc-4-1g4-1-in-ubuntu-10-0410-10) and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1569706). That latter uses the source from gnu.org.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't revert to an earlier version of g++ unless there was no other possible way to achieve my desired results. `g++` is available for all supported versions of Ubuntu in [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B&searchon=names) and can be installed with `sudo apt install g++` If you do indeed need multiple versions you'll want to utilize [How to choose the default gcc and g++ version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version) as @boomkin indicated in [this comment.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210871/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-g#comment1842558_210877)

Comment: apt get install g++-7 doesn't allow to install specific version, like 7.2, the question is exactly how, step by step, install specific g++ version if installing g++-7 gives a wrong one

Comment: @stiv Personally I wouldn't revert to an earlier version of g++ unless there was no other possible way to achieve my desired results. What is it you are attempting to accomplish?