# diff between x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc and plain old gcc?

Tags: 13.04, compiling, gcc

I'm trying to compile something called a "Voice Cloning Toolkit" for Festival and HTS.
(see: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jyamagis/software/page37/page37.html)

I've found that lots of things break with gcc-4.7, so I downgraded gcc, to 4.6, like so:
    sudo apt-get remove gcc-4.7 cpp-4.7 g++-4.7
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 50
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 50
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp /usr/bin/cpp-4.6 50

But now I am running into:
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I./portaudio-v19/include/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
unable to execute x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1

Apparently, I can apt-get install gcc to restore the x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc program, but then the other HTKLib stuff won't compile (because installing gcc always gives me the 4.7 version).

So anyways, what the heck IS this x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc command?  Can I have it, whilst keeping the gcc-4.6?

Comment: For anybody still having this issue, please see here https://askubuntu.com/a/837621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ls /usr/bin/x86* -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jun  3 01:27 /usr/bin/x86_64 -> setarch
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jun  3 01:27 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp -> cpp-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jan 30 13:55 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp-4.4 -> cpp-4.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr 13 06:08 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp-4.6 -> cpp-4.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jun  3 01:27 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp-4.7 -> cpp-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr 22 02:44 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -> g++-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr 15 07:12 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.7 -> g++-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr 22 02:44 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> gcc-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jan 30 13:57 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.4 -> gcc-4.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr 13 06:10 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.6 -> gcc-4.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jun  3 01:27 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.7 -> gcc-4.7
```

...
There is no difference it would seem; try changing the link and see if it works.

Comment: @kenf can you please tell me how to change a link? Because I am also getting the same error "error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
"