# problem installing an older version of gcc

Tags: installation, gcc, matlab

problem installing an older version of gcc

Hi,

I'm new to ubuntu:)

I'm trying to compile a program in Matlab using mex (Matlab), but I'm getting an error that I'm using gcc version 4.6.3 and the currently supported version with mex is 4.4.x.

So I downloaded gcc 4.4.3, but when I try to open it using Ubuntu software center, I'm getting an error: Dependency is not satisfiable: gcc-4.4-base (=4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1).

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can anyone please help? any help will be greatly appreciated as I'm quite stuck.

Thanks in advance,

Gil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download a package manually. Just install it using Software Centre and it will download the appropriate packages for your installation! That's how easy Software Centre works.

Click here: [gcc-4.4 [image: Install gcc-4.4]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc-4.4).

Then use `gcc-4.4` to invoke that specific version. Your `gcc` will be kept the default version though. If you really need to change the system default, see [Choose gcc and g++ version](https://askubuntu.com/q/26498/88802)

Comment: @user175405 If this was helpful and solved your issue, consider accepting this answer by using the check mark.