# How to install two different compilers?

Tags: software-installation, gcc, clang

I am an unskilled Ubuntu user and almost each time I try to install something nontrivial I break something miserably. I am successfully using **gcc 4.7** and **4.8** simultaneously using **update-alternatives** according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/26518/64420). Now I would like to try out **clang** for my C++ development.

I am afraid that the complier is a critical part of the operating system and installing it is nontrivial. I am afraid that if install clang it will overwrite the C++ standard headers and libraries of gcc and/or break something else.

How can I safely install and use clang and gcc?

**EDIT:**

I do not have **aptitude** installed, so I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install clang-3.4
```

instead and everything looks fine. I tested **gcc** and it seems that I did not break it.

Then I tried to compile something with clang and I got this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:38: error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found
#include <bits/c++config.h>
         ^
```

It seems that **clang** is trying to use the **gcc standard library**. How can I solve this?

Comment: your edit basically changes the question you asked. mark this one as resolved and open another one. likely on a different site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely compiling everything yourself. if you are 'unskilled' (I don't think so, just new) ubuntu user I would highly suggest the `deb` maintainers do the hard work for you.

so check to see if apt-get has a copy which you want to use by searching like so.

`aptitude search clang`

if it does great it will handle things, if not you can download tar ball [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.0)

Extact it to `/usr/local` or `/opt` from there you can use it and delete the entire folder if you wish without any affects on your system.

Goodluck.

Comment: so should I just `sudo apt-get install clang-3.4` ?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik yes. search was to so you could see what you could install.