# Downgrade gcc from 4.8 to 4.7

Tags: 14.04, gcc

I have downloaded the latest version of ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 LTS. The gcc version is `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`. I would like to change it to the `4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012]`.

I will be very thankful if you could please help me through it.

Comment: You can have several compiler versions installed at the same time. Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version