# Upgraded to 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS. Now C++ program does not compile

Tags: 14.04, compiling, g++

As the title states, I am having problems compiling my program, and the error is C++11 specific. Is there some way I can go back to the compiler I had on 12.04? Do I need to install another version of g++ and then use that? I googled around but I cannot find what shipped with 12.04. I just need an older alternative to the compiler 14.04 comes with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install g++ 4.4, 4.6 or 4.7 from the package `g++-4.X`. (Then compile your program with `g++-4.X` instead of just `g++`.)

For reference, the default g++ version in Ubuntu 12.04 is [4.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=precise&section=all).

Comment: I noticed I had 4.6 installed, but trying to change it to use 4.6 compiler by default, using the method listed in the question:

[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version)

did not work. I manually changed the symbolic link in /usr/bin/ to point to g++ and that worked fine. So problem solved.

Comment: Apparently `/usr/bin/g++` is just a symlink to `/usr/bin/g++-4.8`, so you can *try* to make it point to `g++-4.6` instead (*i.e.*, `sudo ln -snf /usr/bin/g++-4.6 /usr/bin/g++`). It could cause some problems if you ven compile system things like kernel modules, though, so I wouldn't recommend it (but since it's easily undoable, I guess it doesn't really hurt to try).

Comment: There was a type in my post. I did exactly what you said and I can compile my program now.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using the new `g++`, and specify the standard to be used:

```
-std=
   Determine the language standard.   This option is currently only
   supported when compiling C or C++.
```

For `12.04`, [`man g++`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/g++.1.html) says:

```
gnu++98
   GNU dialect of -std=c++98.  This is the default for C++ code.
```

So compile your code with:

```
g++ --std=gnu++98
```

---

However, [`man g++`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/g++.1.html) on 14.04 says:

```
gnu++98
gnu++03
   GNU dialect of -std=c++98.  This is the default for C++ code.
```

So it would look like the default standard hasn't changed.

Are you sure of the source of your error?