# having problem with g++

Tags: gcc, g++

instead of g++ command O have to type g++-6 -v how do i fix this so that g++ command to g++-6

[image]

this is giving me problem compiling native extensions from ruby and might be trouble for other programs too

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more proper fix for this would be to make a symbolic link for `g++-6` to `g++`. This will ensure compatibility with many installers and other applications.

To do this:

`sudo ln -s $(type g++-6 | grep  -oE '[^ ]+$') /usr/bin/g++`

This will get the path to `g++-6` and create a symbolic like using it to `/usr/bin/g++`

Answer (score 0):

Work around.

Open your `.bashrc`:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add this line to the end of the file:

```
alias g++='g++-6'
```

Then `source` your `.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

One liner:

```
echo "alias='g++=g++-6'" >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @Hector - If it answered your question please upvote the answer and accept it as a token of thanks.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve it. Well... it *does* but not enough so. An alias is not a sufficient fix for something like this.