# NVIDIA driver randomly not found -- fails "Building kernel modules" upon reinstalling

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with a GTX 1070. I use this machine for Tensorflow, with GPU support enabled. I rebooted my system randomly the other day, and now I can't login. I can get to the login screen, enter my password, but then it directs me back to the login screen. I can, however, enter the command line through Alt+Ctrl+F1.

When I try to install any driver from source (I don't think the driver version matters because I've tried several different ones), I get an error:

`ERROR: An error occurred while performing the step: "Building kernel modules". See /var/log/nvidia-installer.log for details` and then `The NVIDIA kernel module was not created`

I've tried uninstalling from source `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57-no-compat32.run --uninstall` and then reinstalling from source, but the same thing. I've tried updating from source `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57-no-compat32.run --update` but the same thing happens.

I've tried installing from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

Which doesn't fully fail, but it outputs an error related to the kernel again: `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic`

Here's what I get when I check for the driver after the PPA install:

```
$ nvidia-smi
modprobe: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_367'
modprove: ERROR could not insert 'nvidia_367': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Maker sure that the latest NVIDIA diver is installed and running.
```

Is this maybe a CUDA issue? How would I go about fixing it if it is?

Should I just reinstall the OS (a fresh install without losing data)?

**UPDATE**

I have an idea of what caused the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I changed my default compiler to be `clang` about a week ago, and I think the NVIDIA driver needs `gcc` or `g++`. I'm not sure how to change it back (a co-worker changed it). I tried this `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 ~/.local/bin/gcc` but that didn't help.

[This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-361/+bug/1564425) bug talks about a config file pointer to clang, but doesn't exactly tell me how to point it back. How can I point the config file back to `gcc`?

Comment: Try doing `sudo rm .Xauthority` from the command line.

Comment: @AndroidDev I have no file `~/.Xauthority` however I think I might know what caused this, I changed my default compiler to `clang` I believe. Do you think this is a compiler issue? What should the default compiler be? Also, I updated the post with the error message I get when I run `nvidia-smi`

Comment: @AndroidDev canyou please explain why is this particular question is duplicate of that in your opinion ?  It looks like OP is having more of a driver problem

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a compiler issue. I believe I had `clang` set as my default compiler. I followed instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version) and Ubuntu now sees my NVIDIA driver just fine.