# Switch between two version of gcc

Tags: 16.04, compiling, gcc, python3

By default my system uses gcc 5.4.0 in ubuntu 16.04 to run a specific program l need to switch to gcc 4.8.

My question is the following :

How can l switch to gcc 4.8 before running the program and come back to gcc 4.8.4 once l've finished.
The program l have to run is in python :

```
# what to do befor running the program
# python3.6 main.py
# how to come back to the gcc version by default
```

Here are the differents gcc version l have :

```
dpkg -l | grep gcc | awk '{print $2}'
gcc
gcc-4.8
gcc-4.8-base:amd64
gcc-4.9
gcc-4.9-base:amd64
gcc-5
gcc-5-base:amd64
gcc-6-base:amd64
gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
lib32gcc1
libcaca0:amd64
libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64
libgcc-4.9-dev:amd64
libgcc-5-dev:amd64
libgcc1:amd64
libpackagekit-glib2-16:amd64
libunity-action-qt1:amd64
libwebrtc-audio-processing-0:amd64
qtchooser
qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin:amd64
```

EDIT1
Is it correct if l do the following  as suggested  [in https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version)

Have l set that correclty ?

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 30

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 30

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 40
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 40
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
```

But l stack at the last command :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

do l need to set that as :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --config g++-4.8
```

and when l want to come back to gcc 5 l set it to :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc-5
sudo update-alternatives --config g++-5
```

Am l right ?

**EDIT2**
l need to run python3.6 with gcc 4.8.4 .
The default gcc version of python3.6 is 4.4.7

```
root@ahmed-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~# python3.6
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How can l change that ?

Comment: @ignite,  please see my update. The difference with the link you suggested is that l have three different gcc version,  so l'm not sure whether l did the right job. l stack mainly at the last step when switching  to gcc  4.8 and coming back to 5. Can l tell me please if l did it in the righ way

Comment: `gcc` is a compiler - it should have no effect on your programs at runtime. So, for example, when you see `GCC 4.4.7` in the `python3.6` version information, it's just telling you what compiler the python3.6 executable was *built* with - you can't change that **without recompiling python3.6**.

Comment: Seems the whole question is misconceived and that is the real answer @steeldriver