# gcc versions later than 5 are not supported while compiling ethminer

Tags: nvidia, compiling, gcc, cuda, cmake

### Important stuff:

Hello users of Ubuntu. Recently I have decided to step into the Ethereum mining world and compile `ethminer` myself. After installing `cuda` however, I ran into a small problem. While doing `sudo cmake --build .` after `cmake .. -DETHASHCUDA=ON -DETHASHCL=OFF`, the console outputted this:

```
[  0%] Built target BuildInfo.h
[ 29%] Built target devcore
[ 41%] Built target ethash
[ 45%] Building NVCC (Device) object libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
CMake Error at ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o.Release.cmake:222 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/diamond/ethminer/build/libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir//./ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o


libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/ethash-cuda_generated_ethash_cuda_miner_kernel.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:232: recipe for target 'libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libethash-cuda/CMakeFiles/ethash-cuda.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

### Additional info:

I installed CUDA using `sudo apt install cuda`. It installed `nvidia-275` and `cuda` itself (along with a lot other stuff)

Comment: IIRC there are some cmake variables you can use to specify a particular gcc to use; try for example adding `-D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin gcc-4.9"` (assuming you have gcc-4.9 installed)

Comment: Got it working. `sudo apt install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9` then from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version/26500#26500), do `ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep -oP "[\S]*(gcc|g\+\+)(-[a-z]+)*[\s]" | xargs bash -c 'for link in ${@:1}; do sudo ln -s -f "/usr/bin/${link}-${0}" "/usr/bin/${link}"; done' 4.9`

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/bin/g++
sudo apt install gcc-5 g++-5
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-5 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-5 /usr/local/cuda/bin/g++
```