# Can't install GCC 7

Tags: package-management, gcc

I'm using codenvy, and it run Ubuntu with GCC 5.4. I want to update the C++ of it to C++1z. I've installed GCC 7 with this commands

```
 $ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
 $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
```

but the main GCC remains outdated:

```
 $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Ubuntu version:

```
 $ cat /etc/lsb*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

I'm new on Linux, I used to use Windows. What I need to do?

**Edit**
I just tried `sudo update-alternatives`, but the output says that there is no updates alternatives to gcc/g++

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version see the "update-alternatives" part of the 1st answer.

Comment: @Rinzwind I just tried that, but the output says that there is no updates alternatives to gcc/g++