# Install gcc 5 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, compiling, gcc

I have `gcc 7.3.0` on Ubuntu 18.04.
But I am working on a project where I need gcc less than version 6.
When I tried to install gcc 5.4 using `sudo apt install gcc-5.4`, I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-5.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-5.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-5.4'
```

**What is the appropriate way to install gcc 5.4?**

Comment: Try just `sudo apt install gcc-5`

Comment: try to find it with `apt search gcc-5` or `apt search gcc-6`

Comment: @steeldriver the command worked for me, but when I run `gcc --version`, I still get 7.3.0

Comment: That's normal - the symlink `/usr/bin/gcc` will still point to `gcc-7`. You can either change the symlink (manually - or via `update-alternatives`) or simply call `gcc-5` explicitly when you need it

Comment: @steeldriver, thank you, it worked. Please post an answer and don't forget to include the `update-alternatives`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver), I could solve the problem as following:

**Install gcc and g++**

```
sudo apt install g++-5
sudo apt install gcc-5
```

**Change the symlink to point to gcc 5 and g++ 5**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
```

**Credits:** [How to choose the default gcc and g++ version?](https://askubuntu.com/a/26518/822295)