# g++-5 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: g++

I'm currently trying to install some software (NUFEB) onto my home PC which is running Ubuntu version 19.10. This requires my computer to have the GNU C and C++ compilers gcc-5 and g++-5. I do not have these on this PC; I have gcc-9 and g++-9.

Does anyone know how I might be able to install g++-5 and gcc-5 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Please note that neither

```
sudo apt install g++-5
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
```

work!

Comment: Have you attempted building it with g++-9?

Comment: @vidarlo Yes I have. The issue occurs when I run ./install-sedifoam.sh, errors are thrown if I don't have g++-5 specifically installed.

Comment: This answer to another question may or may not be of use to you :) - https://askubuntu.com/a/1111452

Comment: What error do you get on the g++-5 install?  The install will not change the default g++ link, which will still point to g++-9.

Comment: What errors do you get when you run `./install-sedifoam.sh`? I don't have 19.10, but I just tried it on 18.04 with `OMPI_CXX=/usr/bin/g++-9` and it didn't seem to complain (at least, not until after the link phase, when it complains about `wmake` and `$WM_OPTIONS`)

Comment: Jack Dawson : May be you got an old version of NUFEB ? Latest is https://github.com/nufeb/NUFEB → → `$ git clone https://github.com/nufeb/NUFEB --recursive` ... No issues, gcc -9.3.0 / mpixx -9.3.0 : $ ./install.sh

Comment: @ubfan1 I get the error when installing sedifoam - it gives me the error: 
make: *** [softParticleCloud.dep:4: Make/linux64GccDPOpt/softParticleCloud.o] Error 127 /bin/sh: 1: g++-5: not found

Comment: @steeldriver I think I needed to install OpenFOAM for make to work - you need to use 'of240' in terminal before you run other commands. I'll try changing OMPI_CXX though and see if that works - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I didn't have any issues with the early steps of installation, it was just when it came to using ./install-sedifoam.sh - I think this might be due to the version of OpenFOAM that is uses. I'll try recloning it though and see if it works. - Thanks