# How to install gcc 5.3.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gcc, cuda

I want to install CUDA 8 in my Ubuntu 18.04 which needs gcc 5.3.1. If I use `sudo apt install gcc-5.3 g++-5.3` then it gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-5.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-5.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-5.3'
E: Unable to locate package g++-5.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-5.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-5.3'
```

Can someone please guide me to install gcc 5.3.1?
Thank you.

Comment: Question answered already https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087150/install-gcc-5-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @David `sudo apt install g++-5` is by default installing gcc 5.5 which is not supported by CUDA 8. It is specifically asking for gcc 5.3.1

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gcc-5&searchon=names , 5.5.0 is available.

Comment: @N0rbert I need gcc 5.3.1 but not gcc 5.5.0