# OpenBTS-UMTS on Ubuntu 18.04, make fails: recipe for target 'CLI.lo' failed

Tags: 18.04, make

I'm trying to install OpenBTS-UMTS on Ubuntu 18.04. I ran successfully

```
./autogen.sh
```

and

```
./configure
```

then

```
make
```

fails with the following error

```
Makefile:501: recipe for target 'CLI.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [CLI.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/foo/Downloads/OpenBTS-UMTS/CLI'
Makefile:550: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/foo/Downloads/OpenBTS-UMTS'
Makefile:481: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to solve? Thanks to who will try to help.

Same version of OpenBTS-UMTS compiled and installed successfully on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18 use g++-7 by default, the problem is related with static const data members may be initialized in the class declaration. This is the problematic declaration:

> ../UMTS/UMTSRadioModem.h:181:28: error: ‘constexpr’ needed for
>   in-class initialization of static data member ‘const float
>   UMTS::RadioModem::mRACHThreshold’ of non-integral type [-fpermissive]
>            static const float mRACHThreshold = 10.0;
>                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141950/initializing-const-member-within-class-declaration-in-c))

To compile OpenBTS-UMTS in your Ubuntu 18, install g++-5: `apt-get install g++-5-multilib` and then configure the g++ versions using update-alternatives (see also this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version))