# Install gcc, g++ and cmake3

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, gcc, g++, cmake

How can I install gcc6.4, g++6.4 and cmake3 on Ubuntu 14.04?
I want to rewrite below lines that run on Linux to be run on Ubuntu

```
$ yum install gcc64-c++ libcurl-devel
$ export CC=gcc64
$ export CXX=g++64
$ yum install cmake3
```

I tried below commands on ubuntu

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y g++-6
$ sudo apt install -y gcc-6
$ gcc --version
$ g++ --version
$ export CC=gcc6
$ export CXX=g++6
$ gcc --version
$ g++ --version
```

But version returned is

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
```

and

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
```

**Although I expect to be 6.4**

And when I tried to install cmake3

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt purge cmake*
 $ wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.5/cmake-3.5.1.tar.gz
 $ tar xf cmake-3.5.1.tar.gz
 $ cd cmake-3.5.1
 $ ./configure
 $ make
 $ sudo make install
 $ cmake --version
```

It gave me an error in ./configure

```
CMake 3.5.1, Copyright 2000-2016 Kitware, Inc. 
--------------------------------------------- 
Error when bootstrapping CMake: 
Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system. 
Please specify one using environment variable CC.
```

Comment: Instead of yum, use apt. Example: `sudo apt install g++`

Comment: If you are familiar with yum, take a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/package-management-basics-apt-yum-dnf-pkg If you are lost, just search on that page for the correct yum command and you get the alternative of apt-get.

Comment: I add more description to the question to be more clearer. Can you please check and give me your advise

Comment: You have installed the packages `gcc-6` and `g++-6` and you should be able to run these commands (`gcc-6` and `g++-6` literally). The system-default version wasn’t _replaced_ as you might have expected. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version BTW, a terminology notice: _“lines that run on Linux to be run on Ubuntu”_  Ubuntu is Linux, too.

Comment: I added below command sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6  and now gcc version is correct but cmake still gave me the same error

Comment: I guess you are using Ubuntu 14.04 from your GCC version. If you need more recent GCC and CMake version, why don’t you upgrade Ubuntu and get them automatically? You should be also able to install [`cmake3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/cmake3) using APT on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You are correct I'm using Ubuntu version 14. But I can't upgrade it. its a certain version given by aws CodeBuild. Is there anyway to install cmake3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS ?

Comment: I found another docker that Ubuntu version 18. But it gives me the same error.

Comment: Likely `export CC=gcc6` and `export CXX=g++6` should be `export CC=gcc-6` and `export CXX=g++-6` (check the actual names using `ls /usr/bin/gcc*`)

Comment: “Is there anyway to install cmake3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS ?” Yes, as I indicated, you should be able to simply run `sudo apt install cmake3` to get [CMake 3.5.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/cmake3).

Comment: I used Ubuntu 18 and its working. Thanks a lot for your support :)