# Change gcc Version for Single User

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, gcc

I have a new version of gcc installed from source in my directory on a larger computer system which has another (older) version used as default. I have a few programs I need to compile using this newer version so I need to switch the version my system automatically uses somehow.

The newer gcc verion has a set of executables in `gcc_9_2/bin/` that look like:

```
g++-9.2   gcc-9.2   gfortran-9.2
```

i.e with version numbers attached.

The simplest thing that occurred to me was to change `$PATH` so that the directory containing the newer versions was searched first, but I don't know how to do that and `export` just adds directories to the end of the path (which won't work). Then remove the version numbers from the executables such as `gcc-9.2` to `gcc` and similar, though I'd be surprised if this does not cause problems.

I've looked at the answers in [How to choose the default gcc and g++ version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version) but the first response requires sudo permissions (which I don't posses) and the second requires me to `rm /usr/bin/gcc` which again, I don't have permission to do.

TLDR: When I type `gcc` my computer uses one version of gcc, I need it to use a different version and I don't have permission to edit the directory where the old version is installed

Comment: *"`export` just adds directories to the end of the path"* no, it adds them wherever you tell it to ex. `export PATH=/my/special/gcc/path:$PATH` will add to the front

Comment: So it does. However after doing that and checking `gcc --version` I still get the old one, whether I change the filename 'gcc-9.2' to 'gcc' or not.

Comment: `gcc` is typically just a symbolic link to the current version; if your local installation did not create such a link you would need to do it manually ex. `ln -s gcc-9.2 path/to/gcc_9_2/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `alias` command to override a command.

```
alias gcc="/home/username/pathtogcc/bin/gcc"
```

This is often used for built-ins like `ls`, e. g. when using it like

```
alias ls="ls -l"
```

Comment: This also has the advantage that you can simply run `\gcc` to execute the systemwide gcc installation.

Comment: ... it has the disadvantage that, by default, it will only apply when `gcc` is invoked directly in an interactive shell (not when it's being invoked from a Makefile or other build process for example)

Comment: Thanks that worked! However my cmake seems to completely ignore this and use the old version anyway, even if I give the location of the new compiler at the beginning of my `PATH`.

Comment: @CT1234 that was exactly my point - for `cmake` you can set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and/or (for C++) `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` explicitly instead ex. `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="path/to/gcc-9.2/bin/gcc-9.2" ../`