# Ubuntu 18.04 installation bug

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation

Desktop specs - > 128 GB RAM, i9-9980xe , 2xRTX 2080Ti , Mobo - MSI creator X299

For the past week or so I have been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 as Dual boot with Windows 10 pro on my newly assembled desktop. No success.

18.04.1/.2/.3/.4 (18.04 released yesterday as well tried) all have been tried but just doesn't install. In .3 and .4 even the mouse cursor doesn't appear while installing, I used my keyboard to navigate the install menu. Once it (seemingly) is done installing, it freezes at the login screen and stays there. That's when the mouse cursor appears and when I move it, it reacts after 15-20 seconds. I type my password in but it doesn't log me in and stays as it is till I force shutdown.

I tried ubuntu 19.10 however, it works seamlessly. I however can't use 19.10 as its not LTS and a lot of problems are appearing while installing CUDA,CUDnn,etc

I have been making bootable pen drives from rufus and ubootnetin on windows. Tried 4 usb sticks.

I wish to install 18.04 along windows 10 pro Thanks in advance for suggestions

Comment: Seems like you have conclusively demonstrated that two-year-old 18.04 does not seem to be compatible with your much newer hardware. Sorry, but that's not a surprise. Happy to see that 19.04 works properly - that's a positive indicator that 20.04 will work properly too. For CUDA on 19.10, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181959/installing-cuda-10-and-tensorflow-2-0-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: If willing to suffer possible breakage and maybe contribute to fixes, install 20.04. When I built a system in 2016, I had to install 16.04 several months before final release. Often best to also plan a total reinstall after release as so many updates make for a lot of cruft.  Use good backup procedures and houseclean regularly.