# How to install g++ 10 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: g++

I would like to explore concepts and other new features in C++20, provided by g++ 10. However, I cannot seem to find any resources that allows me to apt-get a g++ 10 online?

What is the easiest way for me to get g++10 installed?

Comment: "the easiest way"...Life is hard.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`gcc-10` is now available in the Ubuntu tool chains.

Add the PPA and install gcc-10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gcc-10
```

For `g++-10`:

```
   sudo apt install g++-10
```

At the end you need to update the alternatives for compilers ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/26518/689474)):

```
#Remove the previous alternatives
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++

#Define the compiler
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 30
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 30

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++

#Confirm and update (You can use the default setting)
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Comment: It only seems to go up to 9 there?

Comment: @JasonC Did you add the PPA?

Comment: Yup: https://pastebin.com/raw/Efa3hSdk

Comment: hmm...May be, you could upgrade to Bionic or focal? You could also compile gcc yourself from sources if you're willing to take that route.

Comment: Yeah... :( I'll probably just build it from source. This machine is... let's just say upgrading Ubuntu is probably a deeper rabbit hole than I want to go down right now. Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonC I've a little script you might find useful for installing gcc from source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pponnuvel/commons/master/gcc_install.sh

Comment: For those Googling around and finding this answer: You can get 11.1 from the tool chain repository, too!

Comment: Is possible install only "g++" without "gcc"?

Comment: @CloudCho Yes. Just skip the line that install gcc.