# Install GCC/G++ 10 on Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, ppa, gcc

I'm trying to install GCC 10 on my machine as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192955/how-to-install-g-10-on-ubuntu-18-04). After adding the PPA, here's what I keep getting:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Atteint :1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Atteint :2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease         
Atteint :3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.10/prod eoan InRelease     
Atteint :4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease      
Atteint :5 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Atteint :6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu precise InRelease
Atteint :7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease              
Atteint :8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Atteint :9 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease        
Atteint :10 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease     
Atteint :11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Atteint :12 http://apt.insync.io/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Atteint :13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Atteint :14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait                          
$ sudo apt install gcc-10
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet gcc-10
$
```

While it's all in French, you can see on line 6 that the toolchain PPA was reached. The last line says that package gcc-10 could not be found.

Note that I had to add the PPA through the software center, as `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` would simply keep the terminal hanging.

Any idea?

Comment: Why using precise?

Comment: What should I be using intead?

Comment: 20.04 is focal. You should change precise to `focal`.