# gcc/g++ 10 is installed but I can not use it on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: software-installation, gcc, versions, g++

I used the information here [How to install g++ 10 on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192955/how-to-install-g-10-on-ubuntu-18-04) to install gcc/g++ 10 on Ubuntu 20 and when I try to do it again:

```
sudo apt install g++-10

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++-10 is already the newest version (10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but when I ask for the version:

```
g++ --version

g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

**Update**

However when I try:

```
g++-10 --version

g++-10 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It seems like g++10 is installed and usable under the name g++-10 but how can I make it the default g++ compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use `update-alternatives` to specify which version of g++ should be used by default. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Configure `update-alternatives`:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 40
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 60
   sudo update-alternatives --config g++
   ```

After running the last command, you'll be presented with a menu of `g++` versions and you will have the option to choose your default `g++` version. The message will look something like this:

```
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Type the number from the menu you would like to have as default, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you need to change the default version of `g++` again in the future, use the command again.

***Note:** If you need to change the default version of gcc as well, follow this same procedure, replacing* `g++` *with* `gcc`. *Do not forget to change the version numbers as well.*

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep. Just spotted that a few seconds before your comment. Updated 