# how to fix gcc import error issue

Tags: gcc

I have an ubuntu 19 and I am trying to change the version of my gcc to 4.8.5 from 7.8 ( I suppose ). After I tried using this command

```
link in ${@:1}; do sudo ln -s -f "/usr/bin/${link}-${0}" "/usr/bin/${link}"; done' 4.8
```

which is from this link

[How to choose the default gcc and g++ version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version)

after I tried to use gcc -v or gcc --version or even trying to compile anything with gcc I get the error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

what should I do to solve this and get gcc 4.8 as new version

Comment: Ubuntu 19?   Ubuntu desktop and server releases us the format *yy.mm*, with only specialist release using *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances) but there were no specialist releases in 2019 (an odd year). Please clarify your release, added to which your  `gcc` versions don't seem to match any releases (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gcc)

Comment: You can have as many gcc/g++ versions as you want, installed at the same time. Using, examples : `gcc-4.8 file.c` .... `export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && [other command]` .... `make CC=gcc-4.8`. .... Alternatively you can setup links with /etc/aternatives/ ... ( sudo update-alternatives --config gcc .... etc. etc.)

Comment: Do you have an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set somewhere (in your `~/.bashrc` for example)? What is the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do a fresh install leaving only the gcc version that you need/want.
Uninstall all g++ and gcc and do a fresh install. Purge them if necessary.