# nvidia 390 drivers will not build

Tags: drivers, nvidia

[image]

## Background

While using Ubuntu 22.04.3, I switched from the proprietary nvidia **driver** to nouveau in an attempt to get my second monitor working again. Upon reboot, the display was not detected.

So I **reinstalled** Ubuntu using a USB installer. However, now I am stuck at the screen above on a fresh install. The colored pixels appear after a few seconds.

### Graphics Card

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices

vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF119 [NVS 315]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

---

## Driver Installation

### Via apt and ubuntu-drivers

Boot into `recovery mode` by holding <kbd>shift</kbd>. Enable networking while plugged into ethernet so that new drivers can be installed. Enter root to tinker with drivers.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nouveau*
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
$ sudo apt-get purge libnvidia*


$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Errors were encountered while processing:
  nvidia-dkms-390
  nvidia-driver-390
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-dkms-390

see logs at /var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-390.0.crash
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is a gist of that `.crash` file. I see a lot of type errors and warnings, so maybe the driver itself is bugged?
https://gist.github.com/aiqc/96a906344d789ad5c8834ecf5b602b58

### Via Settings UI

If I try to update the nvidia driver through the settings UI, I get similar errors.

[image]

### Via Nvidia's `.run` files

Similar errors
https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/101818/en-us/

### Via ppa

I have tried installing the ppa drivers, and even downgraded my OS to match the specific version mention on the ppa page (22.04.2)
[https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install  nvidia-graphics-drivers-390 
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-390

$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
Errors were encountered while processing:
  nvidia-dkms-390
  nvidia-driver-390
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

## Workaround

If I resume boot in recovery mode after deleting the drivers... it runs the OS with graphics:

> llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)

Comment: I see a gcc-12 mentioned in your build log -- you need to use the same gcc version (gcc-11) the rest of the system uses to build modules.

Comment: @ubfan1 thanks for the suggestion. following the directions at this link, i just tried after ensuring gcc11 was enabled on 22.04.1 but am receiving the same error about the nvidia-dkms-390 and nvidia-driver-390 packages https://askubuntu.com/a/1331764/849369

Comment: Did you truncate your output when installing the packages directly?  "Errors were encountered" does not provide debugging data, we need *all* the `apt` output.  You also don't need the graphics driver PPA, nvidia-driver-390 is still in the 22.04 repos, but we need all the output from `apt` during installation to try and assist you.

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494273   Looks like the 6.5 kernel uses gcc-12, but the Nvidia 390 needs gcc-11. Can you drop back to a 6.2 kernel?

Comment: @ThomasWard did you happen to see the gist I provided? the output was outrageously long

Comment: @ubfan1 thank you for the suggestion and evidence. I spent too much time on it, so I am currently waiting for a refurbished AMD alternative to arrive

Comment: Update: the AMD drivers were so well supported that multiple monitors were functional as soon as the USB installer boot screen reached its boot screen

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, you need to downgrade your kernel version from 6.5 to 6.2.0-26-generic. Once done, repeat the driver installation steps, and you should be able to install the nvidia-driver-390.

fallback kernel version to 6.2.0-26-generic:

[image: fallback kernel version to 6.2.0-26-generic]