# nvidia installer is using older version of GCC by default

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, gcc

I'm using Ubunut 22.04, I want to install nvidia driver: `sudo ./cuda_12.1.0_530.30.02_linux.run`, but I get a warning first:

```
   warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
     The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
     You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
   
   Warning: Compiler version check failed:
   
   The major and minor number of the compiler used to
   compile the kernel:
   
   x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
   
   does not match the compiler used here:
   
   cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
```

I already followed [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/26502/1033376) to change the version to 12.3, and when I check from the terminal I get gcc/g++ version 12.3.

Finally I get an error: `cc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero'`, can you please tell me how can I solve that? thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something here will help: [Unrecognized command-line option ‘-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero’ when building kernel module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766795/unrecognized-command-line-option-ftrivial-auto-var-init-zero-when-building-ke)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the gcc version explicitly

```
CC="gcc-12" sudo ./cuda_12.1.0_530.30.02_linux.run
```

solved this issue.